# Friend Function of Class produces error: "no '___' member function declared"

Tags: c++, friend, access-control, friend-function

I have a class, and I am trying to create a friend function to operate on the data of that class.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
// test.hpp
class test
{
public:
    friend void friendly_function();
private:
    int data;
};

void test::friendly_function()
{
    data = 0;
}
```

However, the compiler spits out an error: `test.hpp:23:34: error: no ‘void test::friendly_function()’ member function declared in class ‘test’`

I know I can declare operators in this way, like so:

```
class test
{
public:
    friend const bool operator<(const test& _lhs, const test& _rhs);
private:
    int data;
};

const bool test::operator<(const test& _lhs, const test& _rhs)
{
    return (_lhs.data < _rhs.data);
}
```

So why can't I do this with `friendly_function`? Are friend functions only allowed as operators?

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to figure out the problem before I posted this question, so it seemed sensible to give the answer, as other people might find it useful in future. I have also set the answer to "community wiki", so other people can improve it if they wish.

The problem is that the friend functions are not members of the class, and therefore must be coded without the `test::` specifier, since they are not members of `class test`.

The declaration `friend void friendly_function();` must be inside the test class however, as this tells the compiler that `friendly_function()` is allowed access to the private members of `test`.

Since `friendly_function()` is not a member of `class test`, it would be a good idea to put all this code together in a namespace, which will group all the functions and classes inside one logical block.

```
namespace test_ns {
    class test
    {
    public:
        friend void friendly_function(test &_t);
        friend bool operator<(const test& _lhs, const test& _rhs);
    private:
        int data;
    }; // class test

    void friendly_function(test &_t)
    {
        _t.data = 0;
    }

    bool operator<(const test& _lhs, const test& _rhs)
    {
        return _lhs.data < _rhs.data;
    }

} // namespace test_ns
```

That should solve the problem. Friend functions are kind of subtle in that they may look like member functions, but actually aren't!

Comment: I know this has been asked (*somewhere* within this vast pool of questions), but you really didn't have to make it CW. It's a well laid out answer and it's perfectly fine to gain rep answering your own questions if you figure them out and want to help others.

Comment: This doesn't compile. I still get a `error: 'data' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @chris I don't get it. It is asked and answered **wrongly** by the same person instantly. `friendly_function` CAN access private members, but it needs OBJECT to do that on non-static members. How's that helpful in any way?

Comment: @PetrBudnik, Sorry, I was elaborating on the layout of the answer and kind of skimmed over the content and took the +1 score and the fact that they seemed to have solved their problem with it as an indication that it was right. I see what you mean, and it's a simple fix. I'll just add it in.

Comment: @chris I do not question your expertise in C++ - I see what you write on SO. In fact, I don't think I am even in a position to question it. And if you wrote a nice review about using `friends`, quoting Standard etc - I'd upvote with two hands without even reading it, knowing it'll be a thorough and a useful one. But I feel this question merely asks `are operators different from functions in a specific way when you use them as friends` and triumphantly proclaims `no!`. Why should they? And why, say, `friend` declaration appears in `public` section? It's misleading as if it should be there...

Comment: Anyway, I might be seeing it all wrong. I don't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: @PetrBudnik What was my mistake?

Comment: @chris Why did you remove the  `const` from the boolean return type? Well spotted with my other error though.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, You were right. I just reread the question after not having the whole operators vs normal functions come through the first time. There should still be an error in the case of the operator using `test::operator<` (and Clang does give one), and that directly answers the question, which I missed with my other edit to fix the syntax issues. Just like operators, friend functions need an instance to work on, and the top level const in the return type is ignored and often gives warnings. As for the location, the access specifier has no effect on friends. No offence detected O_o

Comment: @EdwardBird I, personally, find it a bit odd when a question which is neither well-formulated nor well-researched gets answered wrongly by OP same minute it is posted. It would not be a big deal (I thought, it would be just voted as a duplicate - there are a lot of questions that deal with different aspects of `friend` functions). But when someone with **chris**'s reputation approves it, he then, inevitably, has to improve it (a lot), while not getting credit for it. I felt this is unjust and wanted to point it out. Once again, I honestly don't mean to sound offensive to anyone.

Comment: @PetrBudnik I don't really understand the problem. I was unable to find a duplicate, which is why I was asking the question. Then I stumbled on the answer when I was researching. (By accident, I didn't find the answer on here.) People make mistakes, what's the big deal?